# How to compare two tensors regardless of order

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I want to check if two tensors are equal, but they're unordered. Like the example below.

```
import tensorflow as tf
y_pred = [0,1,2], y_true = [1,2,0]
```

If I use `Y = tf.equal(y_true, y_pred)`

```
session = tf.Session()
session.run(Y)
```

then the output will be `array([False, False, False])`

My expectation is that if the elements between tensors are equal, then the output will be `True` . So, my question is which function should I use, thank you all.

Comment: You can do that by creating `collections.Counter`s out of them and comparing with `==`, but I don’t know if there’s a preferred TensorFlow way or something.

Comment: thanks! I use `tf.bincount`. It works like `collections.Counter`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the tensorflow documentation described [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/equal)

tf.equal()

Returns the truth value of (x == y) element-wise.

This means that the method only works for ordered set.

Just sort the elements and store it in a temp variable. use the sorted temp variables for comparison. I believe there are python functions out there which allows you to sort the list easily.

```
import tensorflow as tf
y_pred = [0,1,2]
y_true = [1,2,0]

y_pred_sorted = sorted(y_pred)
y_true_sorted = sorted(y_true)

Y = tf.equal(y_pred_sorted, y_true_sorted)
session = tf.Session()
session.run(Y)
```

Result:
**array([ True,  True,  True])**

Comment: Sorry, I can't sort the tensor for some reason. I just want to know if they have the same elements. Still thanks for your response.

Comment: if you are using tensor, you may need to reshape it to 1D list first, then apply the technique above

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, I found a way to solve it.

```
import tensorflow as tf
y_pred = [0,1,2]
y_true = [1,2,0]

y_pred = tf.bincount(y_pred)
y_true = tf.bincount(y_true)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

y_pred.eval() == y_true.eval()
```

then the output is `array([ True,  True,  True])`